# toggle on/off click event on unordered list

Tags: jquery, toggle, each

Within a separate function, I'm coding `.addClass("active")` to each list-item to test a condition that will toggle the `click` event `.on()` and `off()` of the selected list-item's siblings. The click event is turning off for the siblings when the condition returns true (*active class added*), but I can't seem to turn it on again once the condition returns false (*active class removed*).  Also if someone would help me write the loop for the on/off function instead of my coding a bunch of "if" statements for each list-item, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

```
$("#mainList").children().each(function(i){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            var currItem = i;
            var currItemSiblings = $(this).siblings();                  

            if(currItem == 0) {
                  functionfirst();
                  console.log(currItemSiblings );
                  if($(currItem ).hasClass("active")){
                      currItemSiblings.off("click");
                  }
                  else{
                      currItemSiblings.on("click");
                  }                 
            }    
            if(currItem == 1){
                 functionSecond();                    
            }    
            if(currItem == 2){
                 functionThird();
            }     
        });
    });  

    functionfirst(){
      // do stuff...fadeToggle <li>#1 content 
      // addClass active to the selected list-item
    }

    functionSecond(){
      // do stuff...fadeToggle <li>#2 content 
      // addClass active to the selected list-item
    }

    ...
```

**Edit**:

Fiddle per my comment below

[http://jsfiddle/eg4Lg8vs/](http://jsfiddle.net/chris2011/eg4Lg8vs/)

Comment: Post your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with markup.

Comment: There is too much code in the original and I thought that snippet would at least help to determine if I am using the `click` event check in the right place. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris2011/eg4Lg8vs/) with a bare bones idea of the functionality I am trying to achieve.  I want the `click` event toggled on/off for the siblings of the target `<li>`. I may need to create an object for this feature to avoid scope issues.